# Qual è il significato di "tenere" in questo testo?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel racconto *La novella dell’apprendista esattore* di Beppe Fenoglio ho letto questo dialogo:

> – Allora, – disse Giulio, – Davide approfittasse di questo po’ di tempo per lasciare la casa e darsi ai boschi. 
>         – No, no, – disse Umberto, – sarebbe molto peggio. Io non me ne intendo, ma dev’essere un’aggravante. 
>         – Già, – convenne subito Giulio, – e poi non ha piú l’età per darsi ai boschi. D’altronde, non c’è piú boschi che **tengano** oggigiorno. Contro la forza i boschi andavano ancora bene vent’anni fa, ma oggigiorno...

Ho cercato il verbo "tenere" su alcuni dizionari, incluso il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000878.jpg) (continua in queste pagine: [1](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000879.jpg), [2](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000880.jpg),  [3](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000881.jpg), [4](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000882.jpg), [5](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000883.jpg), [6](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000884.jpg), [7](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000885.jpg), [8](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000886.jpg), [9](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000887.jpg), [10](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000888.jpg), [11](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000889.jpg), [12](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000890.jpg), [13](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000891.jpg)), ma ci sono tantissime accezioni che non riesco a capire a quale corrisponda l'uso che se ne fa nel brano sopra citato. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con riferimento alle pagine che hai postato, [riporto il significato illustrato in questa](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000890.jpg):

> *"Non esserci qualcosa che tenga"*
>
> non esistere rimedi, soluzioni, mezzi per ovviare a un problema o a una
> difficoltà o per ottenere un risultato; non esserci sentimenti, convinzioni,
> autorità in grado di durare o opporsi; non essere possibili o accettabili scuse, giustificazioni, rinvii, obiezioni.

Questa espressione si utilizza in numerose locuzioni - alcune delle quali riportate nello stesso file collegato, come ad es.

> Non c'è scusa che tenga
>
> Non c'è amicizia che tenga
>
> Non ci sono santi che tengano (riportata anche [qui](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/santo/))

Da quel che mi pare di capire nel dialogo in questione, uno dei personaggi parla *di darsi ai boschi*, ovvero *darsi alla macchia* (= far sparire le proprie tracce); e l'altro obietta, utilizzando questa espressione, che al giorno d'oggi questo "rimedio" (contro il fisco?) ha perso efficacia.

Da notare inoltre che *non c’è piú boschi che tengano* è un anacoluto.

Comment: Condivido, e aggiungerei forse un esempio come “non c'è scusa che tenga” (o tutti quelli che si possono trovare googlando "non c'è * che tenga", con le virgolette, tra cui un colorito “non c'è Cristo che tenga/Cristi che tengano”: http://www.vocabolariofiorentino.it/lemma/cristo/2760).

Comment: Sì, Davide cerca di sfuggire l'esattore che è venuto a riscuotere una tassa inevasa.